# What is the maximum column varchar size for Composite columns in Oracle

Tags: java, sql, oracle, composite-primary-key

I am trying something like below and getting exception.

```
CREATE TABLE test1( col1 varchar(4000) NOT NULL, col2 varchar(4000) NOT NULL, col3 varchar(4000), col4 varchar(4000), col5 varchar(4000) NOT NULL, col6 varchar(4000), col7 varchar(4000) , PRIMARY KEY(col1, col2, col3))
```

Oracle version => 19.16.0.0.0

exception:
Error report -
ORA-01450: maximum key length (6398) exceeded
01450. 00000 -  "maximum key length (%s) exceeded"
*Cause:
*Action:

Comment: [**ORA-01450**](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96525/e900.htm#1004903) maximum key length (string) exceeded
**Cause**: *The combined length of all the columns specified in a CREATE INDEX statement exceeded the maximum index length. <removed text>*

**Action**: *Select columns to be indexed so the total index length does not exceed the maximum index length for the operating system. See also your operating system-specific Oracle documentation.*

Comment: **maximum key length (6398)**

Comment: You may use different tablespace of larger block size for the index, but 12000 symbols as a primary key seems to be quite strange modelling: use some hashing on text or identify different entities of this text by some attributes at the application side and make it a PK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [blog post](https://blogs.oracle.com/sql/post/how-to-fix-ora-01450-maximum-key-length-6398-exceeded-errors) was written to clarify this specific problem. This is the gist of it:

> The smallest unit of data storage in Oracle Database is the block.
> This defaults to 8k (8,192 bytes).
>
> Each index entry must fit within one block. So the maximum size of an
> indexed value must be less than the block size. Minus some storage
> overheads. In a default installation this means the largest indexable
> value is around 6,400 bytes.

Since your `primary key` is enforcing a `UNIQUE` key (by the creation of a `UNIQUE` index), it also needs to fit into a single block.

You cannot change the block size of an already created database, see: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24693_01/server.11203/e24448/initparams049.htm and https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:226813934564

So, if you really, really want (I do not recommend this) to increase your block size, then you can export your database, create a new database with the desired block size and import the exported database.

However, I strongly recommend the reconsideration of this. Having three textual fields as the `primary key` spells disaster for performance because each time you search by your `primary key` fields values will be compared to very long texts. Hence, it would make much more sense to create a numeric field as the `primary key` and maybe a `unique` index on your three fields if you change the block size or, if possible, implement a cron job which would periodically check for new records whether they fulfill the uniqueness you expect to ease the burden on your RDBMS.